# Git commit doesn't accept summary

Tags: git, gnu-coreutils

So I've recently cloned the gnu-coreutils to see how the programs I use actually work, and to get more familiar with git, especially git's CLI. But when I tried committing a change I made to basename.c by using `git commit src/basename.c` with the description `basename: some-desc`, it returned the error

```
commit-msg: invalid first word(s) of summary line: basename
Interrupt (Ctrl-C) to abort...
Too many errors from stdin
commit-msg: .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG: the editor (editor) failed, aborting
```

This description follows the guidelines from the "HACKING" file included in the repository:

```
Try to make the summary line fit one of the following forms:

program_name: change-description
prog1, prog2: change-description
doc: change-description
tests: change-description
build: change-description
maint: change-description
```

but still git doesn't accept `basename` as the program name.
The names of other programs like `cat`, `base64` and `chcon` work however, so maybe this is just a bug?

I also tried googling the issue, but except for general guidelines on how to format git commit messages I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coreutils repository [sets up](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/bootstrap.conf#n405) Git [hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) in your local clone of the repository. You can find the commit message check in [`scripts/git-hooks/commit-msg`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/scripts/git-hooks/commit-msg).

It is run every time you try to commit. It defines the allowed keywords starting in [line 14](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/scripts/git-hooks/commit-msg#n14):

```
# Keywords allowed before the colon on the first line of a commit message:
# program names and a few general category names.
my @valid = qw(
    arch b2sum base32 base64 basenc nbasename cat chcon chgrp chmod chown
    chroot cksum comm cp csplit cut date dd df dir dircolors dirname du echo
    env expand expr factor false fmt fold groups head hostid hostname id
    install join kill link ln logname ls md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod mktemp
    mv nice nl nohup nproc numfmt od paste pathchk pinky pr printenv printf
    ptx pwd readlink realpath rm rmdir runcon seq sha1sum sha224sum sha256sum
    sha384sum sha512sum shred shuf sleep sort split stat stdbuf stty
    sum sync tac tail tee test timeout touch tr true truncate tsort
    tty uname unexpand uniq unlink uptime users vdir wc who whoami yes

    all copy gnulib tests maint doc build scripts sha\*sum digest
    );
```

`basename` is not among them, but `nbasename` is.

To temporarily disable running commit hooks, specify `--no-verify` during commit.

---

EDIT: I have submitted a patch to the coreutils project to fix this typo: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2022-01/msg00013.html. Let's see :)

---

EDIT: This is now fixed as of commit [95ec19ecbd125598f047a938882f5bba81f0e9a3](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=95ec19ecbd125598f047a938882f5bba81f0e9a3)

Comment: Do you know any reason why basename is not in there?

Comment: @Jan_Lukas no, you'd have to ask the coreutils maintainers for that. I'm not related to the coreutils project in any way and answered this question purely from Git's point of view (and a little bit of poking in the coreutils source).

Comment: It really looks like a typo, given that the command names are sorted.

Comment: @torek you're right. This seems to have been accidentally changed in 2018 with commit [2f438fa9f53250fb3c8b39a95eedd627b5569ca4](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/scripts/git-hooks/commit-msg?id=2f438fa9f53250fb3c8b39a95eedd627b5569ca4)